# How to count bookings if allowing for efficient overlap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I've looked over some SO discussions here and, well at least I haven't seen this perspective. I'm trying to write code to count bookings of a given resource, where I want to find the MINIMUM number of resources I need to fulfill all bookings.

Let's use an example of hotel rooms. Given that I have the following bookings

- Chris: July 4-July 17
- Pat: July 15-July 19
- Taylor: July 10-July 11

Chris calls and would like to add some room(s) to their reservation for friends, and wonders how many rooms I have available.

`Rooms_available = Rooms_in_hotel - Rooms_booked`

The `Rooms_booked` is where I'm having trouble. It seems like most questions (and indeed my code) just looks at overlapping dates. So it would do something like this:

`Booking.where("booking_end >= :start_check AND booking_start <= :end_check", { start_check: "July 4, 2021".to_date, end_check: "July 7, 2021".to_date})`

This code would return 3. Which means that if the hotel theoretically had 5 rooms, I would tell Chris that there were 2 more rooms left available.

However, while this method of counting is technically accurate, it misses the possibility of an efficient overlap. Namely that since Taylor checks out 4 days before Pat, they can both be "assigned" the same room. So technically, I can offer 3 more rooms to Chris.

So my question is how do I more accurately calculate `Rooms_booked` allowing for efficient overlap (i.e., efficient resource allocation)? Is there a query using ActiveRecord or what calculation do I impose on top of the existing query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't think just only a query could solve your problem (or very very complex query).

my idea is group (and count) by `(booking_start, booking_end)` in order `booking_start asc` then reassign, e.g. if there're 2 bookings `July 15-July 19` and 3 bookings `July 10-July 11` then we only could re-assign for 2 pairs, and we need 3 rooms (2 rooms for `July 15-July 19-July 10-July 11` and 1 for `July 10-July 11`.

and re-assign in code not query (we can optimize by pick a narrow range of time)

```rb
# when Chris calls and would like to add some room(s) to their reservation for friends, 
# and wonders how many available rooms.
# pick (start_time, end_time) so that the range time long enough that
# including those booking {n} month ago 
# but no need too long or all the time
scope :booking_available_count, -> (start_time, end_time) {
  group_by_time = \
   Booking.where("booking_start >= ? AND booking_end <= ?", start_time, end_time)
      .group(:booking_start, :booking_end).order(:booking_start).count
  # result: {[booking_start, booking_end] => 1, [booking_start, booking_end] => 2, ... }
  # in order booking_start ASC
  # then we could re-assign from left to right as below 

  booked = 0
  group_by_time.each do |(start_time, end_time), count|
   group_by_time.each do |(assign_start_time, assign_end_time), assign_count|
     next if end_time > assign_start_time
     count -= assign_count # re-assign
     break if count <= 0          
   end
   booked += count if count > 0
  end
  # return number of available rooms
  # allow negative number
  Room.count - booked
}
```

Comment: thank you @lamphan! this is a good start, the only challenge with it now is that this allows for redundant stackability. For example if Chris were reserving July 4-July 14, and then a 4th new person called about the July 4-17 dates, this code would return that only 1 room was booked, which is now an understatement. When the code iterates through top level July 4-14 order, it will "stack" (subtract count) against the July 15-19 order in the second level iteration. However, when the code then iterates through top level July 10-11 order, it will also "stack" against the July 15-19 order

Comment: I am trying to think of modifications that doesn't make this crazy complicated, too

Comment: My current solution... 1) recognize that your code is basically asking, can a given set of dates at a top level be stacked onto something else (iterating through second level), 2) this leads to error where 2 top level things can be stacked onto the same second level thing, so 3) I just reversed it, and wrote code such that the question that's asked is, can the top level thing take ON any other second level things. This way the break is also handy because once the top level thing has taken on something else, it can't redundantly stack anything else... this is wordy I'll paste the code

Comment: My code within the 2 nested iterables: `if start_time > assign_end_time; count -= assign_count; break if count <= 0; end`. This one is passing my specs so far, will continue to look to see if there are other issues

Comment: also minor, but I don't think the order by starting_date is necessary? since we're already iterating anyway...